# How to fix cmake error on payday 2 super blt source in debian buster

Tags: linux, windows, debian, makefile, cmake

I have debian 10 running on a virtual machine inside windows 10.

I have installed build-essential, openssl, libssl-dev, libcurl4-openssl-dev, and cmake.

I am trying to have cmake generate a makefile from a cloned git repository, https://gitlab.com/znixian/payday2-superblt and I was able to generate linux files by using cmake to create a makefile, and executing make on the makefile. However, I realised that I was wanting the windows binaries, not the linux .a and .so libraries.

I ended up adding set(WIN32 true) inside the cmake file, and changing set(UNIX true) to false. Now when I erase the cmake generated code and cache, it tells me this error:
"Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY) (found version "1.1.1d")"

I was able to fix this before by actually installing openssl, although I have it installed NOW, and it is telling me it cannot find part of it? What do I need to install, or where do I need to point cmake for the openssl crypto librarys?

Comment: Some confusion. If you want Windows binary why are you using cmake in Debian?

Comment: @Biswapriyo 
I was using it because I thought you could make windows binaries in linux. Am I entirely wrong?